# how to implement .htaccess file in angular project with no backend

Tags: angular, .htaccess, cache-control, max-age

I need help regarding implementing the .htaccess file in my angular project which doesn't have the backend integration yet at all. That is why I can't make http headers to send the '`Cache-Control`' header as i want it to.

Like currently I'm working on the lighthouse optimization of the project where I need to cache the cacheable resources like images stylesheets and scripts in order to reduce round trip to the server again & again.
Currently I'm getting 70+ resources that needs to be cached but I can't cache each single one seperately, so I decided to go with .htaccess mthod in order to simply defining in one place and getting effect everywhere.

The problem is, despite placing .htaccess file in root directory(src/.htaccess) and adding it's reference in angular.json's assets array, I'm unable to see the desired effect i.e. cache control header is vanished or sometimes showing '`Cache-Control: no-cache`'.

Help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Here's my code sample:

[image]

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well the text in image is very much clear but I've edited and added the file text in question's body. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Can you remove the `IfModule` to see what happens?   That would tell you whether or not that module is actually enabled on your webserver.